# Swift Core Data: How to fetch all items in array?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fetch, nsmanagedobject

I want to delete the existing content of my NSManagedObjects Weather and Currently.

```
let entityNames = ["Weather", "Currently"]
for entityName in entityNames {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    let objects = try(context.execute(fetchRequest)) as? [NSManagedObject]
    for object in objects! {
        context.deletedObjects(object)
    }
}
```

However using this code, I get an error on the 3rd line stating:

> Generic parameter 'ResultType' could not be inferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the generic type of the fetch request

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)
```

then you can even omit the result type

```
let objects = try? context.execute(fetchRequest)
```

And there is a typo. You probably mean

```
context.deleteObject(object)
```

In macOS 10.11+/ iOS 9.0+ you are encouraged to use `NSBatchDeleteRequest`